# What is Asp.net personalization?

Tags: asp.net

Hai ,

I  want to know about asp.net personalization and how to implement this feature?
can u suggest me an example  or a tutorial demonstrating this concept.
I think its a very useful feature in asp.net. I hope to know more about it?

Answer (score 1):

From the Article:

> The simplest form of personalization is to record
>   information about the user, and then
>   to make that information available
>   whenever the user logs on. This
>   requires a kind of persistence that
>   goes beyond session state; to create
>   true personalization, you'll want to
>   create a database that associates the
>   saved information with a particular
>   user, and that persists indefinitely.

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/10/25/libertyonwhidbey.html

Comment: Without using database , can we ?

Comment: Yes you can. You can store the data use other data sources like XML. In fact personalization data can also be stored in web.config. See <profile> tag.

Comment: Another doubt,can do same thing Using Cookie ?

Comment: Cookie is not appropiate for this, as putting in too much of data in a "client file" will be bad. They are also suspectible to XSS. But logically speaking, you can definately store data in Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [very comprehensive article series on ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) from 4GuysFromRolla.com. I use it as a reference for a lot of my work. Highly recommended.